# Wants to convert python datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 28, 9, 39, 5, 601831) to "2021-07-28 09:39:601831+00:00"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

I do have python datetime object as datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 28, 9, 39, 5, 601831) and I need to convert as below format

```
"2021-07-28 09:39:601831+00:00"
```

Any info will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking how to format a date, not convert it. `datetime` is a binary type, it has no format itself

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) it looks like `str(datetime)` is equivalent to `datetime.isoformat(' ')` , producing exactly what you want if the original date has timezone information

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Python. But I know these things are documented. Reading the docs is often the fastest and easiest way to solve problems. The format you want is a variant of the ISO8601 format.

---

The [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) has an example that answer exactly this question. The [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method is used to format dates in the ISO8601 format.

```
>>> from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
>>> datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 17, tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2019-05-18T15:17:00+00:00'
```

And `__str__()` is equivalent to `isoformat(' '):

> *datetime.__str__()*
> For a datetime instance d, str(d) is equivalent to d.isoformat(' ').

Which means that formatting a `datetime` in any way is enough to produce what you want:

```
>>> d=datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 18, 15, 17, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>> str(d)
'2019-05-18 15:17:00+00:00'
>>> 'The time is %s' % d
'The time is 2019-05-18 15:17:00+00:00'
```

The documentation also shows that [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) can be used to create a new `datetime` with a specific timezone

```
>>> d=datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 28, 9, 39, 5, 601831)
>>> d1=d.astimezone(timezone.utc)
>>> 'The time is %s' % d1
'The time is 2021-07-28 06:39:05.601831+00:00'
```